# Swig - store unknown object until next call of C++ function

Tags: python, c++, swig

I am using swig with python to call a function myfunc() written in C++. Every time I call myfunc() I have to generate the same huge sparse matrix. What I would like to do instead, is to create the matrix once, then pass an a pointer of the matrix to python, without reallocating space every time. What I fear is that this could cause some kind of memory leak.

What is the best way to do this?

The matrix is part of Eigen::SparseMatrix.

Is it maybe save to simply pass a pointer back and forth? Python would not know how to handle it, but as long as the space stays allocated, will I be able to reuse the pointer in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is precisely how swig handles an unknown object: It passes a pointer to the object around, together with some type information (a string). If a function takes a pointer of that type as argument, swig will happily pass it that pointer. See the swig docs [here](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIG_nn19).

You just have to make sure the types match up, i.e., you cannot pass say a `MatrixXd*` to python and use it in a function taking a `MatrixBase<MatrixXd>*`, since swig will not know that the types are compatible.

Also, for unknown objects (at least pointers to such), swig will not do any memory management, so you will need to allocate and deallocate the object on the C++ side.

Comment: Thanks. How would you allocate the memory in the c++ function? My first guess was to call by reference, but that is not possible using python, at least as far as I can see. On the other hand, if I pass the pointer as a return value, the space will be freed on return. Do you have an idea how to fix that?

Comment: Regarding static I am not sure. If I call the c++ function from the same pyhton code again, do I get a different address or is the address changed every time?

Comment: To allocate and deallocate memory for an object in C++ you typically use `new` and `delete`. For instance, you could create helper functions `Matrix* makeCache() { return new Matrix(); }` that creates a matrix for you and `void cleanCache(Matrix* m) { delete m; }` that deletes it for you. Then add an argument of type `Matrix*` to your function, and in the function body test if the size of the passed matrix is 0. If so, resize and recompute, otherwise just use it. This is just an example. There are certainly several other ways to achieve basically the same.